# Programmatically recognizing symmetries of a polyhedron

Tags: graph-theory, symmetry

I'm programming something, but I'm stuck at something which more math-oriented people probably can help me with.

I am giving a polyhedron in the following form: for each vertex I get the cyclic order of the neighbors around that vertex. I am also given the complete automorphism group (so not only some generators) in the following form: an array of automorphism in which each automorphism is just an array containing the image of each vertex.

The problem I have is that I won't to recognize which automorphisms correspond to rotation, what the order of that rotation is and what the center is. I also have the same problem for reflections, rotoreflections and inversions. (At least I can recognize the identity)

I know for instance that the reflections only have orbits of size 1 or 2, but rotations of order 2 have the same types of orbits. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you haven't given us enough information.  Is your polyhedron 2-dimensional?  Is it sitting in a euclidean space, or is it abstract?   I suspect you're dealing with a polyhedron in 3-space.  Determining the symmetry type amounts to computing on each face things like: fixed vertices, fixed points on edges, fixed points on the 2-dimensional facets.  These ultimately boil down to understanding the permutations on the vertices and thinking through all the possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely an answer, but maybe it is useful. The program `fullgen`, distributed in [CaGe](http://caagt.ugent.be/CaGe), contains some routines that do this. The routines exactly determine the automorphism group and are written specific for fullerenes (for which you only have 28 possible groups). They are written specific for the way `fullgen` constructs the fullerenes, but maybe there are parts that you can use. I don't know how well your knowledge of languages is, but most comments are in German.

**Update**

OK, so a few months ago we had a guest who had the same question, so I ended up writing the exact program you were asking about. You can find the code here: [group_pl.c](https://github.com/nvcleemp/graphtools/blob/master/planar/group_pl.c)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't say I understand much of the German and the method seems to be very specific for this restricted case and not generally usable.

Comment: Thanks again. This program was exactly what I need and I can understand the comments.